# Incorrect syntax near @Weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there anything wrong among this query? I want to get diffrent amount of Top records

```
OpenConnection();
query.CommandText = @"SELECT TOP @weeks b.name, b.lastname, [Date] 
                      FROM [Scheduling_Employee].[dbo].[Date] AS a 
                      JOIN [Scheduling_Employee].[dbo].[Employee] AS b ON a.[Employee_Id] = b.id";
query.Parameters.Clear();
query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@weeks", (weeknumber*7));

SqlDataReader reader = query.ExecuteReader();
```

The error is:

> Incorrect syntax near @Weeks

Comment: Without Order by there is no guarantee which rows you will get back as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for `TOP` is either `TOP x` where `x` is a fixed number, or then

```
SELECT TOP (@variable)
```

if you want to specify a variable (you need to put it in parenthesis).

So try this code:

```
query.CommandText = @"SELECT TOP (@weeks) b.name, b.lastname, [Date] 
                      FROM [Scheduling_Employee].[dbo].[Date] AS a 
                      JOIN [Scheduling_Employee].[dbo].[Employee] AS b ON a.[Employee_Id] = b.id";
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: don't you need to declare @weeks?

Comment: @Beth: it's being supplied as a parameter - no?